Spiral CNC Milling Toolpath for a Complex Shape
I working in the domain of Single Point Incremental Forming (SPIF) and am relatively new to the CNC milling. I am trying to fabricate a Car Hood (screenshot enclosed) by generate a spiral CNC milling toolpath. Unfortunately, I have not had any success with trying various software such as Fusion 360, NX12 etc. Please advise.
enter image description here

Consider to focus on a specific aspect within your objective. SE is not well suited for general advice and would not be useful for this general question.

I would advise stamping a car hood, not milling one.

Toolpaths can be simplified with a proper orientation of tool axes.  Is your "spiral" the usual combinations of circular and linear? Toolpaths often need to be approximations (in lines and arcs) for complex geometry. How close will your toolpath need to get? Is it possible with the size of your tool?

Thank you @fred_dot_u, Tiger Guy and Abel for your response.
My apologies for not being able to explain my problem well. So I will take a very simple example, of a truncated pyramid and its toolpath as shown above

Thank you fred_dot_u, @Tiger Guy and Abel.
I have also included the spiral toolpath

Thank you fred_dot_u, Tiger Guy and @Abel. My focus is only on Single Point Incremental forming rather than conventional metal sheet fabrication techniques such stamping, spinning, bending etc.
Here is a YouTube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nM47ukoKTiQ&pp=ygUTaW5jcmVtZW50YWwgZm9ybWluZw%3D%3D

Now my question is:
How do I get the path defined in top most image for a non-convex, and difficult geometry such as a car hood shown at bottom?

Toolpath is a function of an end result and a tool.  Supposing you are milling with a ball end from above, you would offset the surfaces by the ball radius. You could approximate it into points you need to hit with the center of the ball and G01 (line) point to point. All the fancy software tend to hane the ability to do this for you along with docs on how.

Thanks @Abel for your response once again. I have been to figure out the solution using Fusion360 in Autodesk courtesy the Autodesk Community forum.

Post your solution, preferably with screenshots and step by step directions as an answer so it helps others who search and end up here
